# Google Structured Data Testing Tool scrapes different schema type than on webpage

Tags: google-search-console, microdata, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm currently working on a website for my student group, a performing team. The website will have upcoming performance information, so I thought I would use microdata to setup upcoming performances as structured data Events. On each performance page, the performance is given an itemtype of "Event".

The pages are correctly given this type, as can be seen by using Inspect Element on the webpage. But when I try looking at the page through Google's Structured Data Testing Tool, the type detected is "event", and so the custom Event itemprop's are seen as errors. Is there something I am doing wrong in my implementation of microdata?

[example page](http://www.caltaiko.org/performances/caltopia-2014)

[Testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=www.caltaiko.org%2Fperformances%2Fcaltopia-2014)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google’s SDTT always displays the Schema.org types in lower case (which is an error, as they are case-sensitive). But it doesn’t affect anything, it’s only a problem with their page.

As far as I can see, Google is parsing your markup correctly: The property [`photo`](http://schema.org/photo) is not valid for `Event` (only for `Place`), and the property [`summary`](http://schema.org/summary) isn’t defined at all, hence also not valid.

The "Missing required field `name`" might be misleading: It doesn’t mean that the `name` property is required by Schema.org, it only means that Google requires it for displaying their Rich Snippet.

Comment: Thank you!! I should have checked the schema.org definition more carefully -__- I was following [Google's guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/164506) to Event markup, but maybe it's out of date. Thanks again!

Comment: @JayGee: On this documentation, they are using Data-Vocabulary.org ([`http://data-vocabulary.org/Event`](http://data-vocabulary.org/Event)) instead of Schema.org ([`http://schema.org/Event`](http://schema.org/Event)).

Comment: Ahh I see, that explains it. Thanks for all the help!